# Is there a class or namespace feature within AutoIt?

Tags: autoit

I have multiple files using the same function names. Is there a way to differentiate the two?

Comment: Something similar to public/private for a specific file would solve my problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoIt does not provide a method to do this. You will need to give each function a unique name. You could prepend the filename onto the function name, kind of a poor-man's namespace.

Comment: My Solution was to compile each module into it's own exe, worked perfectly.